# System crashes / logs out after visiting specific website

Tags: macos, google-chrome, crash, performance, web-browsing

This might be a weird question, but I'm asking for some guidance for how to investigate this more. It's not a reproducible issue, but it happens often enough (e.g. a couple of times a week). Here's what happens:

When I visit this website: https://time.mk with Google chrome on MacOS 10.13.5 and a 13" MacBook Pro (2016), the entire OS freezes, not just the Chrome tab. I get the spinning beach ball and the computer is unresponsive.

Now, sometimes I wait for 30 seconds and the computer resumes as if nothing happened. Sometimes the entire Mac restarts on its own, and sometimes, I get logged out of my account. This happens *only* with https://time.mk which is the weirdest part.

I would appreciate some help on how to debug this efficiently. I don't see anything in particular in the syslogs, and the Chrome crash dumps are binary, so I don't know how to read them.

Comment: I just visited the site using Safari and the link worked fine,  Interesting.

Comment: i tried Firefox, Opera, and Google Chrome and it worked on all 3 browsers.